# How to embed `regex` into the `By.xpath...`?

Tags: java, regex, selenium

I need to locate all elements `li` that belong to `div` with `class` starting from letters alabama. It could be `class="alabama12"` or `class="alabamaNY"` or any other

The following code locates only those `li` elements that belong to exactly `alabama`

```
allElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='alabama']/ul/li"));
```

How to embed `regex` into the `By.xpath...`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not necessary to use regex, XPath is powerful enough for this query:

```
//div[starts-with(@class,'alabama')]/ul/li
```